# PHP producing not correct json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm trying to get a json from mysql to use it for creating a tree view with help of bootstrap treeview ajax. But my php produces the wrong json.

I can't understand where do  `{"1":` also `"2"` `"6"` and `"7"` comes from, since I don't have them in my table.

PHP

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "", "dbname");
$query = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_customers";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
//$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $sub_data["id"] = $row["customersid"];
  $sub_data["customer_name"] = $row["customer_name"];
  $sub_data["type"] = $row["type"];
if ($row["society"]=='')
  $sub_data["parent_id"] = "0";
else $sub_data["parent_id"] = $row["society"];
  $data[] = $sub_data;
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
$output[$value["id"]] = &$value;
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
if($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]]))
  {
  $output[$value["parent_id"]]["nodes"][] = &$value;
  }
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
if($value["parent_id"] && isset($output[$value["parent_id"]]))
  {
  unset($data[$key]);
  }
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

JSON output that i get

```
  {"1":{"id":"78","customer_name":"Holding_1","type":"EPC","parent_id":"","nodes":    [{"id":"77","customer_name":"Ship owner","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"78"}]},"2":{"id":"79","customer_name":"Holding_2","type":"EPC","parent_id":"","nodes":[{"id":"80","customer_name":"Ship owner 2","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"79","nodes":[{"id":"82","customer_name":"Sub Ship owner","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"80"}]},{"id":"81","customer_name":"Ship owner 1","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"79"}]},"6":{"id":"83","customer_name":"Ship owner","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":""},"7":{"id":"84","customer_name":"Shipyard","type":"Shipyard","parent_id":""}}
```

JSON format which i need

```
[{"id":"78","customer_name":"Holding_1","type":"EPC","parent_id":"","nodes":    [{"id":"77","customer_name":"Ship owner","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"78"}]},{"id":"79","customer_name":"Holding_2","type":"EPC","parent_id":"","nodes":[{"id":"80","customer_name":"Ship owner 2","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"79","nodes":[{"id":"82","customer_name":"Sub Ship owner","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"80"}]},{"id":"81","customer_name":"Ship owner 1","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":"79"}]},{"id":"83","customer_name":"Ship owner","type":"Shipowner","parent_id":""},{"id":"84","customer_name":"Shipyard","type":"Shipyard","parent_id":""}]
```

MySQL Table

```
customers_id  customers_number society   type       customer_name
    78          46546                    EPC          Holding_1 
    79          53456                    EPC          Holding_2 
    83          763645                   Shipowner    Ship owner 
    77          324543            78     Shipowner    Ship owner 
    84          63465435                 Shipyard     Shipyard 
    80          534523            79     Shipowner    Ship owner 
    81          836754            79     Shipowner    Ship owner 
    82          8746546           80     Shipowner    Sub Ship owner
```

Comment: Why did you use &$value inside the foreach header?

Comment: I took example of this php code from a tutorial and just modified it for my table: http://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/make-treeview-using-bootstrap-treeview-ajax-jquery-with-php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial `$data` array is an indexed array. To each key is assigned an item array. Each item array has the key `parent_id` and a value >= `0`...

...The `1`, `2`, `6` and `7` are the indexes in the initial `$data` array, at which the value for the `parent_id` key of the corresponding item array is `0`.

In order to obtain what you need, you have to reset the array indexes of `$data` before printing it as json-encoded string:

```
//...

$data = array_values($data);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have exactly solved the problem that way.

Comment: `unset($data[$key]);` deleted array `$data` at certain indexes. i was confused why does `json_encode` show the indexes at all. because I've tested that code with another table and it worked properly. But yes, overwriting the array did help.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Database normalization is required.

CREATE TABLE `vtiger_customers` (
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `society` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: thank you for the answer. I had to solve the problem without altering the table.